# Spring-Boot jsonFormat automatically adds time to the Date field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a user class like this

```java
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public Date date;

    public User(String name, Date date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

when I send the this data in request body

```json
{
    "name":"exampleName",
    "date":"1998-07-05"
}
```

I recieve the input like this

```
name---->exampleName
date----> Sun Jul 05 05:30:00 IST 1998
```

( i don't want the time to be included in this field)
Also, I cannot change the variable type from Date to LocaleDate

Comment: please try this
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: A `Date` object always has a time associated with it.

Comment: @JsonFormat makes ObjectMapper transform the target field with particular format, so if you serialize the User object with ObjectMapper the date field will look like "1998-07-05", but toString() for the object will be still "Sun Jul 05 05:30:00 IST 1998". Look at the example [here](https://github.com/firstsarcasm/stack-overflow-answers/blob/master/answer-5/src/test/java/com/github/firstsarcasm/SerializationTest.java).

Comment: To deserialize Date with time as 0 you can use [custom deserializator](https://github.com/firstsarcasm/stack-overflow-answers/blob/master/answer-5/src/test/java/com/github/firstsarcasm/DeserializationTest.java)

Comment: @AlexandrArhipov The date has already time 00:00 GMT.

Comment: @Olivier time, hours, minutes, etc.

Comment: `java.util.Date` (despite the terrible name) is a timestamp with date and time. If you want only a date I strongly suggest the new `LocalDate` class (which really is a `Date`) else this simply isn't possible. I would suggest removing the thing that prevents you from using that.

Comment: Your requirements contradict themselves. If you want to keep the Date type, then you have time automatically. You could set it to 00:00, but it is still there.
You could keep the type Date in your User class but when processing it, you can convert it to LocalDate dropping the time information. When you're done, construct a new Date again.

Answer (score -1):

you need to check if you send data as you wish to accept it,in controller class you need to put this to accept the data as you want `@PostMapping("/date")
public void date(@RequestParam("date")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") Date date) {

}`